# iPhone app release date option in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

I submitted my iPhone application to iTunesConnect.Now it is in "Waiting for review". I want to release it only when i decide.. But am not able to see the option to set release date as "Automatically after success review"  or "release date will be set by Developer"(I mean Version Release Control option) . Somebody please help me ..Thanks in advance..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the App Store.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think they changed this recently:

> You can only use the Version Release
>   Control on app updates. It is not
>   available for the first version of
>   your app since you already have the
>   ability to control when your first
>   version goes live, using the
>   Availability Date setting within
>   Rights and Pricing.

Make sense?

Answer (score 6):

You must set Availability Date in the Rights and Pricing section from the app screen.

Answer (score -1):

Availability of an app is edited in the Availability Date in the Rights and Pricing section when in the summary of your app.